# SQL Server 2014 on Windows 10

Tags: .net, sql-server, windows, .net-3.5, sql-server-2014-express

I am trying to install SQL Server 2014 on Windows 10 but it requires .NET Framework 3.5 SP1. I have tried enabling the windows feature but for some reason this does not work on my machine. I then thought I would download a full version on .NET 3.5 framework eg from

http://www.techdreams.org/microsoft/download-offline-installers-of-net-framework-35-35-sp1-30-20-from-microsoft-servers/1845-20090314

The file is around 231 mb but when I run this file I still get a page which says 'Windows needs to download files....' and then I get that same error as enabling the windows feature which is 'Windows cannot download the files, not connected to internet'. I am connected to internet .... sure of that.

Please help. How can I install 3.5 framework on my machine

Comment: There's a discussion here on how to add 3.5 without downloading anything manually. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/newmsn/forum/newmsn_install-newmsn_updateapp/i-cant-install-sql-server-2014-on-windows-10/6d311401-796f-4b3f-b5be-d310cfa6454c?auth=1

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the .net 3.5 framework using the following command in the terminal with administrator permissions:

For x86 architectures use the following:

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:D:\x86\sources\sxs /LimitAccess
```

For x64 architectures use the following:

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:D:\x64\sources\sxs /LimitAccess
```

Where **Source** is the path to the **sxs** folder from your Windows 10 installation root folder. In my case I had a windows 10 iso, so I mounted the iso file and run the following command in the console:

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:D:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess
```

Note: in my case I don't have the platform folder because the iso I download was for x64 only.